# What‘s my CPU's strategy to guarantee cache consistency?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Currently, CPUs has multiple cores, and each core has its own cache(s). There are some method to make sure the cache consistency like **snooping cache consistency protocol** and **directory based cache consistency protocol**. I don't know what my real CPU uses to make sure cache consistency. It is Intel(R) COre(TM) i7-8550U CPU @1.8GHz. Thanks!

Comment: Intel has manuals for that. Which manuals have you downloaded and studied so far?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983405/what-is-the-benefit-of-the-moesi-cache-coherency-protocol-over-mesi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983405/what-is-the-benefit-of-the-moesi-cache-coherency-protocol-over-mesi).

Comment: Your [4c8t Coffee-Lake CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/122589/Intel-Core-i7-8550U-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz) uses a variant of MESI (called MESIF) over a ring bus.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner at hardware things. So thank you all!