# Do I need to use smp_mb() after binding the CPU

Tags: c, linux, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

Suppose my system is a multicore system， if I bind my program on a cpu core, still I need the `smp_mb()`  to guard the cpu would not reorder
the cpu  instructions?

I have this point because I know that  the `smp_mb()`  on a single-core systems is not necessary,but I'm no sure this point is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rarely need a full barrier anyway, usually acquire/release is enough. And usually you want to use C11 `atomic_load_explicit(&var, memory_order_acquire)`, or in Linux kernel code, use one of its functions for an acquire-load, which can be done more efficiently on some ISAs than a plain load and an acquire barrier.  (Notably AArch64 or 32-bit ARMv8 with `ldar` or `ldapr`)

But yeah, **if all threads are sharing the same logical core, run-time memory reordering is impossible, [only compile-time](https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/).**  So you just need a compiler memory barrier like `asm("" ::: "memory")` or C11 `atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)`, not a CPU run-time barrier like `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` or the Linux kernel's SMP memory barrier (`smp_mb()` is x86 `mfence` or equivalent, or ARM `dmb ish`, for example).

See [Why memory reordering is not a problem on single core/processor machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217821/why-memory-reordering-is-not-a-problem-on-single-core-processor-machines/59224016#59224016) for more details about the fact that all instructions on the same core observe memory effects to have happened in program order, regardless of interrupts.  e.g. a later load must see the value from an earlier store, otherwise the CPU is not maintaining the illusion of instructions on that core running in program order.

---

And if you can convince your compiler to emit atomic RMW instructions without the x86 `lock` prefix, for example, they'll be atomic wrt. context switches (and interrupts in general).  Or use `gcc -Wa,-momit-lock-prefix=yes` to have GAS remove `lock` prefixes for you, so you can use `<stdatomic.h>` functions efficiently.  At least on x86; for RISC ISAs, there's no way to do a read-modify-write of a memory location in a single instruction.

Or if there is (ARMv8.1), it implies an atomic RMW that's SMP-safe, like x86 `lock add [mem], eax`.  But on a CISC like x86, we have instructions like `add [mem], eax` or whatever which are just like separate load / ADD / store glued into a single instruction, which either executes fully or not at all before an interrupt.  (Note that "executing" a store just means writing into the store buffer, not globally visible cache, but that's sufficient for later code on the same core to see it.)

See also *[Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837731/is-x86-cmpxchg-atomic-if-so-why-does-it-need-lock)* for more about non-`lock`ed use-cases.